# Can skip mapping for key paramsURL and key uri

Tags: ios, objective-c, mapping

I have JSON body:

```
    0 =     {
        city = Luxembourg;
        firstName = "Dr. Anna-Maria";
        id = 724;
        lastName = "Boehler (Bohler)";
    };
    1 =     {
        city = Rodange;
        firstName = Joanna;
        id = 1542;
        lastName = "Kotlewska (Biever)";
    };
    2 =     {
        city = Luxembourg;
        firstName = "Dr. Joanna";
        id = 1681;
        lastName = "Louwagie (Hoche)";
    };
    3 =     {
        city = Luxembourg;
        firstName = Magdalena;
        id = 2161;
        lastName = "Sarrazin (Owsianna)";
    };
    4 =     {
        city = Diekirch;
        firstName = Anna;
        id = 10822;
        lastName = "Kogut-Aramini";
    };
    paramsURL =     {
        country = 1;
        name = Anna;
    };
    uri = "search-by-name";
}
```

**ShowListResultResponse.swift:**

```
import UIKit
import Foundation

class ShowListResultResponse: NSObject {

    var id: Int?
    var firstName: String?
    var lastName: String?
    var city: String?

    override init() {
        super.init()
    }

    init(id: Int, fristName: String, lastName: String, city: String) {
        self.id = id
        self.firstName = firstName
        self.lastName = lastName
        self.city = city
    }
}
```

Code that adds a mapping for the ShowListResultResponse class:

```
    RKObjectMapping *showListDoctorMapping = [RKObjectMapping mappingForClass:[ShowListResultResponse class]];
    [showListDoctorMapping addAttributeMappingsFromDictionary:@{
                                                                @"id" : @"id",
                                                                @"firstName" : @"firstName",
                                                                @"lastName" : @"lastName",
                                                                @"city" : @"city"
                                                                }];



     RKDynamicMapping *mapping = [RKDynamicMapping new];
        [mapping  setObjectMappingForRepresentationBlock:^RKObjectMapping *(id representation) {

        NSDictionary *dict = representation;
        NSArray *keys=[dict allKeys];
        RKObjectMapping *dataMapping =[RKObjectMapping mappingForClass:[ShowListResultResponse class]];
        for (NSString *key in keys){
            if ([key isEqualToString:@"paramsURL"] && [key isEqualToString:@"uri"]){
//if key equal paramsURL and uri               
 //can skip mapping

            }else {
                [dataMapping addRelationshipMappingWithSourceKeyPath:key mapping:showListDoctorMapping ];

            }
        }
        return dataMapping;
    }];

    _doctorSearchDescriptor= [RKResponseDescriptor responseDescriptorWithMapping:mapping method:RKRequestMethodAny pathPattern:@"/search-by-name"  keyPath:@"" statusCodes:statusCodes];
    [[RKObjectManager sharedManager] addResponseDescriptorsFromArray:@[_doctorSearchDescriptor]];
```

When building this code and searching for a doctor's name, I get an error stating that "this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key id."

Comment: Is RKObjectMapping written in objective-c? It might be that `id` is a reserved type in objective-c. Try changing the name from `id` to identifier and see if that helps.

Comment: RKObjectMapping written in Objective-C